# Как обратиться к элементу из форму?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Генерируемая форма. Количество пунктов неизвестно.
Поэтому name задал при помощи [].
После проверки формы приходит JSON объект, в котором хранятся ошибки

```
errors:
    name.0: ["Поле name.0 обязательно для заполнения."],
    test.0: ["Поле test.0 обязательно для заполнения."]
```

Как, при помощи jQuery, выбрать input с ошибкой?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="test[]" value="">
  <input type="text" name="test[]" value="">
  <input type="text" name="test[]" value="">
  <input type="text" name="test[]" value="">
  <input type="text" name="name[]" value="">
  <input type="text" name="name[]" value="">
  <input type="text" name="name[]" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: А где пример JSON?

Comment: Добавил фрагмент Json, в таком виде он у меня отображается в console.log

Comment: То что вы добавили в вопрос, это не JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

мб так

```js
let json = {"name.0": ["Поле name.0 обязательно для заполнения."], 
      "test.0": ["Поле test.0 обязательно для заполнения."]};

for(let item of Object.keys(json)) {
  let [,name, index] = item.match(/(.*)\.(\d+)/); 
  console.log( $(`input[name='${name}[]']`)[index] );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="test[]" value="1">
  <input type="text" name="test[]" value="2">
  <input type="text" name="test[]" value="3">
  <input type="text" name="test[]" value="4">
  <input type="text" name="name[]" value="5">
  <input type="text" name="name[]" value="6">
  <input type="text" name="name[]" value="7">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let responseJson = '{ "errors": { "name.0": ["Поле name.0 обязательно для заполнения."], "test.0": ["Поле test.0 обязательно для заполнения."] } }'; 
const parsed = JSON.parse(responseJson); 

const elems = []; 
Object.keys(parsed.errors || {}).forEach(
  e => e.replace(/^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$/, 
    (m, p1, p2) => elems.push($(`input[name="${p1}[]"]`).get(+p2)) 
  )
); 
$(elems).css('border-color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="test[]" value="">
  <input type="text" name="test[]" value="">
  <input type="text" name="test[]" value="">
  <input type="text" name="test[]" value="">
  <input type="text" name="name[]" value="">
  <input type="text" name="name[]" value="">
  <input type="text" name="name[]" value="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Подключаемся к форме, а потом ищем необходимые нам input. C помощью метода eq - выбираем нужный

```
let $form = $('form').find('input[name="name[]"]');
console.log(form.eq(3)) // Получите 4 элемент
```

Comment: Но я не могу знать в каком пункте будет ошибка и как следствие я заранее не знаю, какой элемент мне понадобится. У меня в Json есть ключ с названием "test.3" (к примеру)